# Iterator inside DictWriter.writerow

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to process a data struct as follows:

```
dict<ID, actions>
```

where `actions` is a list of dictionaries, and each of them contain two pairs (at least): 'gameCode':value, 'gameTime':value.

So my data is like:

```
{user1: [{gameCode : 1, gameTime : 1}, {gameCode : 2, gameTime : 2}], 
user2: [{gameCode : 1, gameTime : 1}, {gameCode : 2, gameTime : 2}]}
```

This data come from a log in which each row represents one action.

I have to produce an output as the following:

> ID | action | time | action | time ...

I was wondering how could I write these pairs of action/times in a *pythonic* way, maybe using a list comprehension. This is what I have so far:

```
    event = 'gameCode'
    data = 'gameTime'

    # Open the .csv file and creates a dict of actions
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in spamreader:
            # Add an empty list for 'userID' if it is not registered yet in dict
            user = row['userID']
            actions = Users.get(user, []) 
            # Delete the 'userID' from the information
            del row['userID']
            # Add a register of actions for this user
            actions.add(row)
            # Update its values
            users[user] = actions   

     # Sort each list of actions based on time      
     for key, value in users.iteritems(): 
        users[key] = sorted(value, key=lambda k: k[data])

     # Write a .csv to be consumed by the app   
     with open('eventsInput.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
         csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
         for key, value in users.iteritems(): 
            actions = [[d[event], d[data]] for d in value]
            writer.writerow([key, 0, 0, 0, 0, [action for action in actions]])
```

I'm stuck at this last line.

With this, I get this output:

L11-13 0 0 0 0 "[['1002', '358']]"

But I don't want nothing but 1002 358 (i.e., no " , ' [ etc)

Comment: Keys are unique in a dictionary, you may need to rethink your data structure. Also you need to pass `fieldnames` to `DictWriter`.

Comment: But they are unique. That's why I have a list of dictionaries. @achampion

Comment: Not if you are trying to output a row `'id', 'action', 'time', 'action', 'time'`, action and time are duplicate keys in the writerow dictionary.

Comment: No. I have a list of dictionaries. I want to access each dictionary in these keys (from each dict) list and get this to write in a csv, not in another dict or something like. Don't know what's the problem about that. There's no repeated keys.

Comment: Can you show what you expect on a single row, and what the fieldnames are for that single row?

Comment: I understood your point through your answer, @achampion. Anyway, I posted how my data looks like (I don't know if I made that clear). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researcher and a lot of trials, I found out that I can accomplish what I want with this piece of code:

```
with open('eventsInput.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
     for key, value in users.iteritems(): 
        # That was what changed the result
        actions = list(chain.from_iterable((d[event], d[data]) for d in value))
        print actions
        writer.writerow([key, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [action for action in actions])
```

Just don't know why I can't do:

```
actions = [chain.from_iterable((d[event], d[data]) for d in value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't have multiple fieldnames with the same value in a DictWriter, you could revert to a normal csv writer (though you might have to deal with uneven lengths of action time tuples for a specific id) or consider that for any id you have a list of actions and a list of times:

```
from csv import DictWriter
data = [{'id': 1, 'actions':[1,2,3], 'times': [1,2,3]},
        {'id': 2, 'actions':[4,5,6], 'times': [4,5,6]}]
with open('fred.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, ['id', 'actions', 'times'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

*fred.csv*

```
id,actions,times
1,"[1, 2, 3]","[1, 2, 3]"
2,"[4, 5, 6]","[4, 5, 6]"
```

When you read it in, you can zip actions and times to get them back together.

Comment: I could do what I was trying to explain. I mean, it worked with the dict the way it is. But the output doesn't match what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your updated code, you can just add lists:

```
writer.writerow([key, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [action for action in actions]])
```

But this may cause issues on read because you may have variable number of fields per row, unless `len(actions)` is a constant.

Comment: I tried this yesterday and the output is L11-13 0 0 0 0 "['1002', '358']"